# Specializing a function for a private class?

Tags: c++, private, friend, template-specialization, specialization

Is there any way to specialize a function (say, `std::swap`) for a private class?

For example, when I test this:

```
#include <algorithm>

class Outer
{
    struct Inner
    {
        int a;
        void swap(Inner &other)
        {
            using std::swap;
            swap(this->a, other.a);
        }
    };
public:
    static void test();
};

namespace std
{
    template<> void swap<Outer::Inner>(Outer::Inner &a, Outer::Inner &b)
    { a.swap(b); }
}
void Outer::test()
{
    using std::swap;
    Inner a, b;
    swap(a, b);
}
int main()
{
    Outer::test();
    return 0;
}
```

I get this:

```
Test.cpp:20:47: error: 'Inner' is a private member of 'Outer'
    template<> void swap<Outer::Inner>(Outer::Inner &a, Outer::Inner &b)
                                              ^
Test.cpp:5:12: note: implicitly declared private here
    struct Inner
           ^
Test.cpp:20:64: error: 'Inner' is a private member of 'Outer'
    template<> void swap<Outer::Inner>(Outer::Inner &a, Outer::Inner &b)
                                                               ^
Test.cpp:5:12: note: implicitly declared private here
    struct Inner
           ^
Test.cpp:20:33: error: 'Inner' is a private member of 'Outer'
    template<> void swap<Outer::Inner>(Outer::Inner &a, Outer::Inner &b)
                                ^
Test.cpp:5:12: note: implicitly declared private here
    struct Inner
```

(I do realize declaring a friend `swap` that can be found through ADL avoids this issue for `swap`, but that's irrelevant to my question. `swap` is just an example.)

Comment: putting a `friend void swap(Inner, Inner)` inside `Outer`?

Comment: @TemplateRex: That's not going to specialize `std::swap`, it's just a nonmember function called `swap`.

Comment: You cannot specialize a class that is not visible.  Since the `struct` is declared with private access, only `Outer` can see it.  Thus, you cannot create a non-Outer-member function that can see it - preventing you from specializing it.

Comment: @ZacHowland: Is there no way to declare it as a `friend`, for example? I feel like there should be, but I can't find any syntax that works... and I don't see why it shouldn't be possible.

Comment: @TemplateRex: uhm if it was then the question would be pointless wouldn't it?

Comment: You would have to declare `std::swap` as a friend to `Outer`, but again, I don't know why you would do that if the `Inner` struct is not visible to anything outside `Outer`

Comment: @ZacHowland: Well, don't worry about the "why"... the question is *how* would I do it?  I can't find any syntax for the friend declaration that works.

Comment: @Mehrdad next try: friend declaration side Outer. see updated answer.

Comment: @TemplateRex: Ahh... yeah I couldn't find the right syntax for declaring a template specialization as a friend, but now I finally did, thanks! Would you like to post it as an answer or should I?

Comment: @TemplateRex: Ah just saw it, thanks!

Comment: nice problem btw, forgot to upvote in all the commotion, done now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a `friend` declaration of the `std::swap<Inner>(Inner&, Inner&)` inside `Outer`

```
#include <algorithm>

class Outer
{
    struct Inner
    {
        int a;
        void swap(Inner &other)
        {
            using std::swap;
            swap(this->a, other.a);
        }
    };

    friend void std::swap<Inner>(Inner&, Inner&) noexcept;
public:
    static void test();
};

namespace std
{
    template<> void swap<Outer::Inner>(Outer::Inner &a, Outer::Inner &b) noexcept
    { a.swap(b); }
}

void Outer::test()
{
    using std::swap;
    Inner a, b;
    swap(a, b);
}

int main()
{
    Outer::test();
    return 0;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=9d05fbeb8213d10b2c094098283b55e8-1bc3b30e7813d939a8572cf8b3e715c2)

Comment: btw the `noexcept` was necessary to shut up further compiler errors (because the primary template has that as well)

Answer (score 1):

Don't extend the `std` namespace.

If you want to create a swap function for `Inner`, make it a private function in `Outer`

```
#include <algorithm>

class Outer
{
    struct Inner
    {
        int a;
        void swap(Inner &other)
        {
            std::swap(this->a, other.a);
        }
    };

    static void swap(Inner& a, Inner& b);

public:
    static void test();
};

void Outer::test()
{
    Inner a, b;
    swap(a, b);
}

void Outer::swap(Inner& a, Inner& b)
{
    a.swap(b);
}

int main()
{
    Outer::test();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1 you're not answering the question. Pretend that `std` was `foo` and `swap` was `bar`, now I'm not extending `std` anymore. How would I specialize `bar` then?

Comment: I did answer it.  You cannot create a specialized method for a function that cannot see a private access `struct`.  Hence, to get the functionality you want, create a private function in Outer called `swap` that calls your `Inner::swap` method.  Since `Inner` is not visible outside of `Outer`, there is no need for a specialized external function, anyway.

Comment: Well, your comment answers it, but your post doesn't. I don't agree that there is "no need" but if it's impossible then that answers my question...

Comment: Also, for this particular question, see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617305/is-specializing-stdswap-deprecated-now-that-we-have-move-semantics

Comment: Yup, I know it's mostly unnecessary in C++11, but I stay C++03-compatible.