# Rationale behind the usual implemention of std::swap overloads

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, swap

Let's consider the following minimal code sample:

```cpp
// Dummy struct
struct S
{
    int a;
    char * b;

    // Ctors, etc...
};

void swap(S & lhs, S & rhs)
{
    using std::swap;

    swap(lhs.a, rhs.a);
    swap(lhs.b, rhs.b);
}
```

---

**Context**

I know that when we intend to ***call*** a `swap()` function, the proper and recommended way to proceed is to do as follows:

```cpp
// Let's assume we want to swap two S instances.
using std::swap;
swap(s1, s2);
```

This way, ADL is able to find the proper overload if any (defined in the given type namespace), otherwise `std::swap` is used.

Then I read some SO threads:

- [How to overload std::swap()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562/how-to-overload-stdswap/2684544#2684544)
- [Is specializing std::swap deprecated now that we have move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8617346/11455384)
- [Move semantics == custom swap function obsolete?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6420425/11455384)
- And some others

where the same idiom is used (even for built-in or pointer types), but not only when we ***call*** the `std::swap()` overload but also when we ***define*** it.

**Question**

If the members are all built-in types (or pointer types, possibly pointers to custom types), is it still necessary/recommended to use that idiom instead of explicitly calling `std::swap()` ?

For example, considering the small code sample I provided, since `S` members are built-in types, is it *fine* (well-formed) to define it as below instead:

```cpp
void swap(S & lhs, S & rhs)
{
    std::swap(lhs.a, rhs.a);
    std::swap(lhs.b, rhs.b);
}
```

Or maybe is there a reason I couldn't see that would still require to use the `using std::swap;` way ?

Comment: In those cases, one reason to use `using std::swap;` is future proofing in case `a` or `b` change and become custom (non-built-in, non-std) types.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I see, it sounds like a good reason. Thanks.

Comment: "If the members are all built-in types", then you probably don't need to implement swap yourself

Comment: @appleapple It may still be needed for performances purposes since a custom swap allows to avoid the creation/destruction of a whole instance of the given type (since there is move semantics, this is the only reason I can see to overload `std::swap` no matter built-in types members or not).

Comment: They are all built ins today. Tomorrow (or in six months) they may not be. That's putting the strain of adding a missing using declaration on an unsuspecting future maintainer. So it's ultimately not about language lawyering at all. In C++20 we can just use `std::swap` on every member and the ADL happens automagically, but C++20 isn't quite well supported enough for that to be a strong point

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica In C++20, ADL still happens even if we explicitly call `std::swap` ? It's strange in my opinion since it changes the observable behaviour of the program (if I were to explicitly prefix `std::`, I expect `std::swap` exactly to be called).

Comment: @Fareanor - Well, it *could* happen. I forgot that in the end `std::swap` was left untouched and `std::ranges::swap` was introduced as a neibloid with the associated magic.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Oh I see, that sounds more reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> since S members are built-in types, is it fine (well-formed) to define it as below instead: [std::swap usage]

Yes. I mean, it works because `std::swap` just ["swaps the values a and b" if they are both `MoveAssignable` and `MoveConstructible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap), which built-in types are.

> If the members are all built-in types (or pointer types, possibly pointers to custom types), is it still necessary/recommended to use that idiom instead of explicitly calling std::swap() ?

Just for the future of your class: if one day any of its members gets replaced with a user-defined type, you might forget to modify your `swap` and miss a "specialized" ADL implementation for it, still calling the generic `std::swap` which could (theoretically) be inefficient yet still compile.

Actually, you don't even need to think about it if you just always use `boost::swap` or implement it yourself:

```
template<typename T> void swap(T& a, T& b) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(a, b);
}
```

Comment: Implementing my own swap as proposed wouldn't be helpful since it would probably never be called (except if I call it explicitly). It's better to save ourselves a function call and to directly use `using std::swap; swap(lhs, rhs);`