# what's the fastest kind of sorting an array?

Tags: c#, sorting

I use selection sort, but I want a better sorting solution than this:

```
    static void SelectionSort(int[] a)
    {
        int temp, pmin;
        for (int i=0; i<a.Length-1; i++)
        {
            pmin=i;
            for (int j=i+1; j<a.Length; j++)
            if (a[j]<a[pmin])
                pmin=j;
            temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[pmin];
            a[pmin] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is Array.Sort(a) not sufficient? (uses quick sort)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C Array sorting tips](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893937/c-array-sorting-tips)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use:

```
Array.Sort(a);
```

Which will do a QuickSort.

Answer (score 2):

If you look on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms), there is a good comparison of different sorting algorithms as far as their space and time complexity. Many are `n lg n` or `n` average time which should suit your needs nicely.

In addition, .NET comes with several sorting algorithms built in. Including [Array.Sort()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort.aspx) and [List.Sort()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

use  `Array.Sort(a)` or `orderby` in [linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546145.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There is no absolute winner in sorting algorithms. The efficensy depends on size, content, state of the array. *You*  only know what is best for you.

Look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80546/Comparison-Sorting-Algorithms-in-C-Explained) for examples and measurement.

Answer (score 1):

just use the built in function in `Array`: `Array.Sort(a)`

Answer (score 0):

To have the fastest sorting algorithm you should use `heap sort` .It has the lowest time complexity compared to all other sorting algorithm

```
A program to implement Heap Sort

#include<stdio.h>

void restoreHup(int*,int);
void restoreHdown(int*,int,int);

void main()
{
    int a[20],n,i,j,k;
    printf("   Enter the number of elements to sort : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Enter the elements : ");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
            scanf("%d",&a[i]);
            restoreHup(a,i);
    }


    j=n;
    for(i=1;i<=j;i++)
    {
            int temp;
            temp=a[1];
            a[1]=a[n];
            a[n]=temp;
            n--;
            restoreHdown(a,1,n);
    }

    n=j;

    printf("Here is it...");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
            printf("%4d",a[i]);
    }



    void restoreHup(int *a,int i)
    {
     int v=a[i];

     while((i>1)&&(a[i/2]<v))
     {
            a[i]=a[i/2];
            i=i/2;
     }
     a[i]=v;
    }

    void restoreHdown(int *a,int i,int n)
   {
    int v=a[i];
    int j=i*2;
    while(j<=n)
    {
            if((j<n)&&(a[j]<a[j+1]))
                    j++;
            if(a[j]<a[j/2]) break;

            a[j/2]=a[j];
            j=j*2;
    }
    a[j/2]=v;
   }
```