# C get cpu usage on linux and windows

Tags: c, windows, linux, io, cpu

I am using below programs on linux and windows to get cpu utilization of current processes.

**Linux:**

```
int main()
{
      int ret;
      char *buf;
      int i=0;
      int who= RUSAGE_SELF;
      struct rusage usage;
      struct rusage *p=&usage;

      ret=getrusage(who,p);
      printf("user time used: %16lf  %16lf\n",p->ru_utime.tv_sec,p->ru_utime.tv_usec);
    printf("system time used: %16lf  %16lf\n",p->ru_stime.tv_sec,p->ru_stime.tv_usec);

      system("ls");
      printf("user time used: %16lf  %16lf\n",p->ru_utime.tv_sec,p->ru_utime.tv_usec);
    printf("system time used: %16lf  %16lf\n", p->ru_stime.tv_sec,p->ru_stime.tv_usec);    

    return 0;
}
```

**Output on linux:**

```
user time used: 0.000000 -1.999568
system time used: 0.000000 -1.999568
a.out check.c
user time used: 0.000000 -1.999568
system time used: 0.000000 -1.999568
```

Does this mean that the system("ls") command did not take any cpu cycles to execute? How do i get the exact cpu cycles used by any command or program?

I am facing similar problems on windows. for the below code.

**Windows:**

```
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
    FILETIME ftCreation, ftExit, ftKernel, ftUser;
    SYSTEMTIME stKernel;
    SYSTEMTIME stUser;

    GetProcessTimes(hProcess, &ftCreation, &ftExit, &ftKernel, &ftUser);
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&ftKernel, &stKernel);
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&ftUser, &stUser);

    printf("\nTime in kernel mode = %uh %um %us %ums", stKernel.wHour,stKernel.wMinute, stKernel.wSecond, stKernel.wMilliseconds);
    printf("\nTime in user mode = %uh %um %us %ums \n", stUser.wHour,stUser.wMinute, stUser.wSecond, stUser.wMilliseconds);

    system("dir");

    GetProcessTimes(hProcess, &ftCreation, &ftExit, &ftKernel, &ftUser);
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&ftKernel, &stKernel);
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&ftUser, &stUser);

    printf("\nTime in kernel mode = %uh %um %us %ums", stKernel.wHour,stKernel.wMinute, stKernel.wSecond, stKernel.wMilliseconds);
    printf("\nTime in user mode = %uh %um %us %ums \n", stUser.wHour,stUser.wMinute, stUser.wSecond, stUser.wMilliseconds);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Above program **output on windows** dev c++:

```
Time in kernel mode: 0h 0m 0s 15ms
Time in user mode: 0h 0m 0s 15ms
<directory listing>
Time in kernel mode: 0h 0m 0s 15ms
Time in user mode: 0h 0m 0s 15ms
```

Can you please let me know how can we get correct cpu usage for the above programs? Also is there a way to get to know IO usage or number of characters read and write to disk/memory?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See my another question for better understanding... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181628/standard-way-of-tracking-calculating-cpu-and-io-usage-of-process

Comment: Did the previous answer's answer your question? Or do you want to get those updating numbers that the windows task-mananger shows?

Answer (score 2):

In the Linux version you've asked for `RUSAGE_SELF`, which is all threads of the parent process, rather than `RUSAGE_CHILDREN` for child processes. For IO usage under Linux you'll need a kernel after 2.6.20, and look in `/proc/[pid]/io`.

I think you have a similar problem on Windows. You'll need to use [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) rather than `system`, so that you can get a handle to the child process and record its times. For IO usage on windows I think you'll need to use WMI, which is a large subject.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried fork option on the Linux. But that is still giving the same times.Same case with windows. Am I missing some thing? Are there any examples similar to the above programs? I am using RUSAGE_CHILDREN as you have suggested.

Comment: @EnjoyCoding - On closer reading RUSAGE_CHILDREN will only return accounting for child processes that have terminated and been cleaned up by `wait`. So I was wrong in my first answer, and `system` should be adequate.

Answer (score 0):

It is the correct output. `ls` is not the current process; whilst `ls` is executing, no CPU time is spent on your process.

BTW Dev-C++ is just a [bad, unmaintained] IDE, not a compiler. You probably meant to say MinGW.

Comment: MinGW is not a compiler either :-)  naaa, i know what you mean of course: gcc is the compiler that is bundled with it and mingw supplies the headers and libraries.

Comment: @eznme: No, it's more than that. The binutils and GCC itself that MinGW ships with libraries and headers are native software ports.

Comment: yes ofcourse. I was just mentioning Dev C++ default installation so that you can get to know what it holds and compiles with. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You made a few errors in the linux version here.

1. As Adrian pointed out, you should use `RUSAGE_CHILDREN` to count in the resource consumed by the child process.
2. You did not call `getrusage()` again after you invoked `system()`.
3. In your `printf()`, you should not use `%lf` which represents a long double type. `tv_sec` is of type `time_t` and `tv_usec` is of type `susecond_t`. In 64-bit linux, they are both `signed long`, which is incompatible with `long double` (note you have negative result here). For portability, you should have used explicit cast, such as:

   ```
   printf("user time used: %ld  %ld\n",(long)p->ru_utime.tv_sec,(long)p->ru_utime.tv_usec);
   ```