# Find CPU utilization for a system in C++

Tags: c++, c, cpu-usage

Is there any library using which i can find cpu utilization of a machine for both windows and linux ?

Comment: Do you want to know what the overall usage is (i.e. 80% currently), or broken down by process?

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272470/c-get-cpu-usage-on-linux-and-windows

Comment: @Nicolas: I want to see the overall usage.

Answer (score 1):

I believe google is the place where you need to search first, a quick search provides one such library.
**[i-scream libstat](http://www.i-scream.org/libstatgrab/)**
It's in C though.