# Efficient median calculation for small dataset in C++

Tags: c++, median

I have many (hundreds of thousands, m) sets of doubles d, ~5-10 (n, **constant small**) long. These doubles are essentially randomly distributed. I need to get the median of each set: because m is very large, we need to calculate the median pretty quickly...these sets are pretty small though, so I think that is going to play a significant role in choosing how to do the median. I know I can use [nth_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element/) to get the median in O(n) with the selection algorithm, which I know I'm not going to beat in complexity. However, because of the small constant n, I am probably looking for the method that simply has the smallest overhead.

I have found a bunch of different ways to do the median (below) but am just curios if anyone knows the "correct" method to use here.

[Min max heaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap) (O(n) build time, constant access, probably too much overhead)

[This question from 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810657/fastest-code-c-c-to-select-the-median-in-a-set-of-27-floating-point-values) Which may be out of date (new STL/Boost code may already implement this stuff), also focuses more on time complexity than overhead.

Comment: Are they `std::set`s of `double`s?

Comment: "Hundreds of thousands" is not "many" by any reasonable standard these days. If you have a couple hundred thousands of 5-10 tuples of doubles, the algorithm won't matter. A crude Python script iterating over the lines, doing a full sort and printing the middle element should do it in a couple of seconds.

Comment: Depends on the latency you are looking for, we are shooting for a "real time" solution, sub 30-60 ms, so the "crude" techniques are not what we're shooting for...if time wasn't an option, I would just go with the n_th element cuz its easy.

Comment: With `m` data sets (and thereby `m` medians by-circumstance) you will be hard-pressed to find the medians in under O(m*N(m)) complexity, where N(m) is the average number of nodes per set.

Comment: Do you know how fast `nth_element` performs with your setup?  How many times faster do you need to be?

Comment: @WhozCraig, Yup, I'm not trying to get smaller complexity, there are a bunch of O(N(m)) median techniques. Since N(m) is small and constant, I really need the median function with the lowest constant time overhead, not (necessarily) the smallest growth complexity.

Comment: Well `nth_element` will probably do the QSort based k-th statistic algorithm underneath. Anything using heaps etc means allocating additional space, which might in and of itself already add more overhead than you can afford. I'd say benchmark `nth_element`, you won't get much above that.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Good point, my current metric is "as fast as possible", though I may be prematurely optimizing.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams The added info about `N(m)` being a constant `n` (you have lottsa-lists, but they're all `n` elements long; this was not evident in the question as-stated) is important. In that you can choose a potentially unrolled algorithm based on that size.

Comment: @WhozCraig Unless it's constant for all invocations, the best option will probably be to create unrolled versions for each `n` and then invoke the appropriate one when needed. Judging by the requirements, any size checking might introduce branching / mess with CPU branch prediction.

Comment: @TC1 I concur. It appears it *is* a small **fixed** constant by the comments and updated question info from the OP. So I think going that route (crafting an optimal unrolled algorithm) is probably the best he'll do. In that it is not significantly different than many fixed-block encryption or hashing schemes, which pretty-much *all* use this technique (albeit their reasoning is backed by *much* more complicated code).

Comment: @BoBTFish, naw the array of doubles that we need to get the median are populated on a "per m" iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not scale well to your data sizes, but it's a code snippet I found (can't remember where) and use in my image processing functions to get the median of 9 unsigned char pixels.

```
// optimised median search on 9 values
#define PIX_SWAP(a, b) { unsigned char uTemp = (a); (a) = (b); (b) = uTemp; }
#define PIX_SORT(a, b) { if ((a) > (b)) PIX_SWAP((a), (b)); }

unsigned char GetMedian9(unsigned char *pNine)
{
    // nb - this is theoretically the fastest way to get the median of 9 values
    PIX_SORT(pNine[1], pNine[2]); PIX_SORT(pNine[4], pNine[5]); PIX_SORT(pNine[7], pNine[8]); 
    PIX_SORT(pNine[0], pNine[1]); PIX_SORT(pNine[3], pNine[4]); PIX_SORT(pNine[6], pNine[7]); 
    PIX_SORT(pNine[1], pNine[2]); PIX_SORT(pNine[4], pNine[5]); PIX_SORT(pNine[7], pNine[8]); 
    PIX_SORT(pNine[0], pNine[3]); PIX_SORT(pNine[5], pNine[8]); PIX_SORT(pNine[4], pNine[7]); 
    PIX_SORT(pNine[3], pNine[6]); PIX_SORT(pNine[1], pNine[4]); PIX_SORT(pNine[2], pNine[5]); 
    PIX_SORT(pNine[4], pNine[7]); PIX_SORT(pNine[4], pNine[2]); PIX_SORT(pNine[6], pNine[4]); 
    PIX_SORT(pNine[4], pNine[2]); return(pNine[4]);
}

#undef PIX_SWAP
#undef PIX_SORT
```

**EDIT** - Ok, it's also referenced [in this answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9721847/2065121)

Comment: Isn't this what nth_element does?

Comment: @MadScienceDreams - if so, then I can't see how you can do better. Might be worth some profiling though. Do you need the *exact* median? There are some algorithms for giving an approximation that *might* be faster.

Comment: Approx may be ok, especially if I have some sense of the probability of correct median...I'll start the search now for "approximate median", but do you have any quick search seeds?

Comment: No, I stumbled across many "approximate median" algorithms but I needed exact. Also found a nice constant-time median filter for images - i.e. independent of window size, but we're off-topic with that.

Answer (score 0):

if it is std::set (you didnt answer to BoBTFish) then it is already sorted. Hence, you will get the median by iterating to n/2 which is always better or equal O(n), typically is should be O(ld n). n-th element will not help here.