# Fastest way to sort 3 values in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I have to put 3 values in correct order and print them out to the console.

A solution is to put them into an array and then sort them, but I remember (from school times) that there was faster to compare and order them, however I can't find the correct comparison order.

Could you please show me how to compare 3 values with the minimum number of `if` statements?

Comment: For three items bubble sort would do just fine.

Comment: For three items [bogosort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) would do fine.

Comment: related: [Fastest sort of fixed length 6 int array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2786899/4279)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no point in optimizing this. It will not gain any speed. O(n!) for 3 is still only 3*2 = 6 operations. Even O(2^n) is going to be 8. You could really do whatever it takes to sort these 3 values and not see a difference in performance.

*edit*

```
int a, b, c, min, max, med;//assume values are there for a b c
if( a > b ){
 if( a > c ){
  max = a;
  if( b > c ){
   med = b;
   min = c;
  }else{
   med = c;
   min = b;
  }
 }else{
  med = a;
  max = c;
  min = b;
 }
}else{
 if( b > c ){
  max = b;
  if( a > c ){
   med = a;
   min = c;
  }else{
   med = c;
   min = a;
  }
 }else{
  med = b;
  max = c;
  min = a;
 }
}
```

Comment: The following code seems not necessary:
`if( b > c ){
   max = b;
   min = c;
  }else{`
Because once a is greater than b, but a is not greater than c, then b will never be greater than c.

Comment: @durban - That is true, this was mostly written to show that explicitly checking all scenarios would not affect the speed of such a small operation. I removed the redundant code.

Answer (score 21):

bubble sort would have only 3 compare ops, and 6 assignments at worst case (it will be very similar if not identical to the behavior of insertion sort in this case):

```
if (a > b)
   swap(a,b)
if (b > c)
   swap(b,c)
if (a > b)
   swap(a,b)
print a,b,c
```

**It cannot be done in less then 3 compares** because there are `n!=6` possible permutations for the array, and `ceil(log_2(n!)) = 3`

Comment: Will the downvoter please elaborate? Is it because of the mathematical proof it cannot be better then 3 compares? or because of the algorithm showing it can be achieved within 3 compares?

Comment: This is basically bubblesort written out. Minsort would let you get rid of one potential swap.

Comment: @millimoose: Yes, it is bubble sort - as it clearly indicated in the first line of the answer. min sort will still need to do 3 compares (find the min - 2 compares, find the new min in the subarray - 1 compare).

Comment: @amit - 3 Compares is best case scenario here because the set is small. Best case scenario for bubble sort is O(n) so that is in line with expectations.

Comment: Thats not exacly what i wanted, but it does the trick somehow. I could use Arrays.sort, but I wanted to use other method. Thank you.

Comment: @TravisJ: It does not matter, bubble sort *worst case* is n-1 + n-2 + ... + 1 compare ops (assuming not extra compare for `breaking out` optimization). when `n==3` it will get you (3-1) + (2-1) = 2+ 1 = 3 compare ops. There is no point to talk about big O when dealing with 3 elements.

Comment: @amit - Bubble sort worst case is O(n^2). There is always a point in talking about time complexity when the topic is optimization.

Comment: @TravisJ While the big-O formula is correct, the fact is that the worst case for `3` elements with a sane bubble sort implementation is `3` comparisons and `2` swaps, not `9` of anything. The big-O notation is a drastic simplification of what's usually a much more complicated and more difficult to determine exact formula for the number of operations; the cost of this simplification is that it's allowed to overestimate to various degrees.

Comment: @millimoose: there is no compare in swap() - only reads and assignments, making it 3 compares. My solution aimed to show an algorithm with minimum number of COMPARES ("lowest tree") and to show it cannot be done with fewer compares.

Comment: @amit My point is that your algorithm isn't the "fastest way" (as asked by the OP), because it doesn't optimise for swaps. (FWIW, I didn't downvote your answer.)

Comment: @TravisJ: Please read the definition of big O notation again, I elaborated it as a comment to your answer. When talking small scale - big O says NOTHING, since the upper bound definition does not include these cases (from the definition of big O).

Comment: @amit - Stated already, and clear from analysis that best case was O(n). If you don't understand the difference between best, worst, and average case with time complexity and big o notation then I am not sure how much of this back and forth you are really going to benefit from.

Comment: @TravisJ Well, the discussion included too many comments and was thus removed, I want only to add the bottom line, hoping it is accepted. Big O notation says: if `f(x)` is `O(g(x))` - then there are x0,M such that for each x > x0: `|f(x)| < M*g(x)`. If x < x0 - all bets are off. We cannot say anything. For example, the function `f(x) = { if x < 10: x^10  | otherwise: x }`. By definition of big O, we will get that `f(x)` is `O(x)`. That said - I am going to sleep, have work tomorrow. You are more then welcome to open a chat and I'll try to elaborate tomorrow - if you are willing to learn.

Comment: "It cannot be done in less then 3 compares" Yes, it can. Consider `a <= b <= c` or `a > b > c`. It cannot be done in less than 2 compares.

Comment: @EcirHana You cannot give a specific example and say "it works with 2 compares on it"  - you need to show a series of 2 compares that works on ALL inputs. This is how lower bound works. Why is sorting is `Omega(nlogn)` problem when clearly you can sort a sorted array in `O(n)`?

Comment: You said that sorting 3 numbers "cannot be done in less then 3 compares", ever. What I said was that if you get lucky, you can spare one compare.

Comment: @EcirHana The implicit intent was worst case complexity, same as sorting an array is Omega(nlogn) problem for worst case complexity

Comment: "implicit intent" by whom? you? OP? OP said "compare 3 values by minimum values of if"...

Comment: @EcirHana I dare you to find a fewer number of comparisons that solves the problem for every input. The problem statement `Could you please show how to compare 3 values by minimium values of if()?` suggests he needs fewest possible "if statements" (interpeted as comparisons), and it supposed to work for every input. A worst case complexity analysis is a very common implicit assumption in literature, and I am not going to argue about either it's correct or not.

Comment: Search for "__sort3" in [libcxx](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/algorithm).

Comment: @EcirHana OK, I see a chain of 3 if conditions comparing values that is reachable for the input x<=y, y>z.

Comment: Ok, whatever. Your answer is wrong.

Comment: @EcirHana I would be happy to agree if you can show me a sorting algorithm for 3 elements that uses less than 3 compares for every input. (Unfortunately, `ceil(log_2(3!)) > 2`, so that won't happen). Good day.

Comment: @EcirHana Why is his answer wrong?

Comment: @EcirHana best case is 2 comparisons, worst case is 3 comparisons. for best case, your guess for middle value should be true. for example if `a <= b` and `c => b` then you don't need to compare `a` to `c`. however if `b` is not middle then you do 3 comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, Java uses the **Quicksort** algorithm for sorting - an already optimized approach. No speed to harvest here!

Comment: Specifically for boundary cases (like sorting just 3 values). Regular sorting algorithms like quicksort might not perform well