# Trouble sorting three numbers in ascending order in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I'm currently working on a program and I just cannot get it to work the way it is supposed to work. I need to enter three integers using a scanner, and then output the numbers in ascending order. I technically got this to work but it didn't follow the structure that it HAS to follow. In my main method I have the declarations and input. Then I have to use a second method that does the sorting. I for the life of me cannot get the numbers to sort at all actually when I put the sorting inside this new method. It compiles, I run it, enter the numbers and it ends the program. Without the second method it runs correct, mostly. When it ran outside the second method there was also some errors I believe in the way that I thought was logical to sort the numbers.

Anyway this is the code that I came up with.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ch5PA1
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
// Declarations
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter three values: ");
int num1 = input.nextInt();
int num2 = input.nextInt();
int num3 = input.nextInt();
}

/** Sort Numbers */
public static void displaySortedNumbers(double num1, double num2, double num3){
if ((num1 < num2) && (num2 < num3)){
    System.out.println("The sorted numbers are " + num1 + " " + num2 + " " + num3);
    }
if ((num1 < num2) && (num2 > num3)){
    System.out.println("The sorted numbers are " + num1 + " " + num3 + " " + num2);
    }
if ((num1 > num2) && (num2 > num3)){
    System.out.println("The sorted numbers are " + num3 + " " + num2 + " " + num1);
    }
if ((num1 > num2) && (num2 < num3)){
    System.out.println("The sorted numbers are " + num2 + " " + num1 + " " + num3);
    }
}
}
```

Another thing, looking around I saw a few questions people asked about the same (or similar) issues I am having with this but the replies insist on using arrays. I cannot use an array at all for this.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Where are you calling the method?

Comment: You need to start by learning the basics of Java. The code you've posted suggests you don't understand how to invoke a method. This isn't the place to learn such things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main method call your method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Declarations
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter three values: ");
    int num1 = input.nextInt();
    int num2 = input.nextInt();
    int num3 = input.nextInt();
    displaySortedNumbers(num1, num2, num3);
}
```

And for more info. about sorting 3 numbers here is an old post:

[Fastest way to sort 3 values in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040240/the-fastest-way-to-sort-3-values-java)

And giving a look to your code, I don't think it's posible to sort 3 numbers just by comparing them 2 times.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. Didn't realize I had left out the call, works now and I'll take a look into the link you posted.

Comment: and you were wondering about not using a collection or array.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a short solution, perhaps you could try something like:

```
public static void print(final int n1, final int n2, final int n3){
    final int highest = n1 > n2 && n1 > n3 ? n1 : n2 > n1 && n2 > n3 ? n2 : n3;
    final int lowest = n1 < n2 && n1 < n3 ? n1 : n2 < n1 && n2 < n3 ? n2 : n3;
    final int middle = n1 != highest && n1 != lowest ? n1 : n2 != highest && n2 != lowest ? n2 : n3;
    System.out.printf("%d > %d > %d", highest, middle, lowest);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The number of orders you can put your numbers are 3! which is 3*2*1 = 6. You have only 4 conditions, so you are missing two of those six. Try to find the remaining ones.

Answer (score 0):

Put them into a List and sort them by `Collections.sort()`

Comment: If he can't use arrays, he probably can't use Collections either.

Comment: If he can't use arrays, he's probably not supposed to find the answer on StackOverflow either...

Comment: Seriously? Does the OP have to go through such drastic measures for sorting **3 numbers**!?

Comment: I thought I was kind of clear but I need help figuring out where I'm going wrong and some help to guide me to the correct path to fix this program. Sorry for not being very clear on that.

Comment: @AustinRay - You need to start by learning the basics of Java. The code you've posted suggests you don't understand how to invoke a method. This isn't the place to learn such things...

Comment: I never said this was a place to learn Java and kill me for leaving off one mistake. Its 2AM, tired after working all day. I think I'm allowed to make one mistake.

Comment: @AustinRay - Yes, you are allowed to make one mistake... This question is hilarious.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you're actually not calling your sorting method anywhere in your code. You'll have to do that and pass the parameters, there's no magical fairy that knows you want to call that particular method.

Also, why are your parameters `doubles`, when you're asking the user for `ints`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to this programming task

```
package studies;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SortIntegers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println(" Enter 3 integers: ");
        int a = input.nextInt();
        int b = input.nextInt();
        int c = input.nextInt();

        // Sort the numbers 

        int  min, max, med;
        if( a > b ){
             if( a > c ){
              max = a;
              if( b > c ){
               med = b;
               min = c;
              }else{
               med = c;
               min = b;
              }
             }else{
              med = a;
              if( b > c ){
               max = b;
               min = c;
              }else{
               max = c;
               min = b;
              }
             }
            }else{
             if( b > c ){
              max = b;
              if( a > c ){
               med = a;
               min = c;
              }else{
               med = c;
               min = a;
              }
             }else{
              med = b;
              max = c;
              min = a;
             }
            }

        //Display results
        System.out.println("The sorted numbers are: " + min + med + max);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
//============================================================
/* (Sort three integers) Write a program that sorts three 
integers. The integers are entered from the input dialogs and 
stored in variables num1, num2, and num3, respectively. 
The program sorts the numbers so that 
                num1 <= num2 <= num3
 */
        int num1, num2,num3;

        System.out.println("Enter three integers to be sorted: ");
        num1 = input.nextInt();
        num2 = input.nextInt();
        num3 = input.nextInt();

        // example 1 2 5
        if ( (num1 >= num2 && num1 >= num3) && num2 >= num3 )
            System.out.printf("Sorted numbers are %d %d %d", num3, num2, num1);
        else if ((num1 >= num2 && num1 >= num3) && num3 >= num2)
            System.out.printf("Sorted numbers are %d %d %d", num2, num3, num1);
        else if ( (num2 >= num1 && num2 >= num3) && num1 >= num3 )
            System.out.printf("Sorted numbers are %d %d %d", num3, num1, num2);
        else if ((num2 >= num1 && num2 >= num3) && num3 >= num1)
            System.out.printf("Sorted numbers are %d %d %d", num1, num3, num2);
        else if ( (num3 >= num2 && num3 >= num1) && num2 >= num1 )
            System.out.printf("Sorted numbers are %d %d %d", num1, num2, num3);
        else if ((num3 >= num2 && num3 >= num1) && num1 >= num2)
            System.out.printf("Sorted numbers are %d %d %d", num2, num1, num3);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use Math.min Math.max to find min, max and median. Than print it in ascending order..

```
    // compute stats
    int min    = Math.min(a, Math.min(b, c));
    int max    = Math.max(a, Math.max(b, c));
    int median = a + b + c - min - max;

    // print stats
    System.out.println(min);
    System.out.println(median);
    System.out.println(max);
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a list add your numbers by using list.add(nubmer) and finally use
Collections.sort( list );

Comment: Already suggested, and there's already a discussion as to whether or not the poster is even looking for a solution using `Collections`.

Comment: When i was posting no answer was there

Answer (score -1):

import java.util.Scanner;

public class my_name {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a,b,c,l=0,s=0,m=0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your first number:");
    a= input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
    b= input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your third number:");
    c= input.nextInt();
    if ((a>b)&&(a>c))
    l=a;
    if((b>a)&&(b>c))
    l=b;
    if((c>a)&&(c>b))
    l=c;
    if ((a<b)&&(a<c))
    s=a;
    if ((b<a)&&(b<c))
    s=b;
    if((c<a)&&(c<b))
    s=c;
    m=(a+b+c)-(l+s);
    System.out.printf("largest number:%d ",l);
    System.out.printf("smallest number:%d ",s);
    System.out.printf("middle number:%d ",m);
    System.out.printf("The ascending order is %d %d %d",s,m,l);
}
}
```

Comment: Please improve your answer by explaining why it would fix the problem exposed in the question, instead of just dropping some code. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for further guidance.