# How do I add speed to my turn based system so if a monster has more speed it attacks first

Tags: godot, gdscript

I made a function that compares the speeds of two monsters the player and the enemy but I dont know how to make them do their attack and then go back to a state where the player can press a button again, at the moment the player attacks and then the enemy attacks without speed being a factor if I change the button to check_speed it becomes an endless loop

This is the code:

```
func check_speed(): # Gonna make it so speed becomes a factor
    if P_team.monster_invetory[0].speed > enemy_scene.speed:
        player_attack()
    else:
        enemy_attack()
        
func player_attack(): # Attacks the enemy
    print("Player attacking")
    enemy_scene.take_damage(P_team.monster_invetory[0].attack) # Calls the function to take damage
    yield(get_tree().create_timer(2), "timeout") #Wait for 2 seconds
    Enemy_battle_scene(enemy_scene) #This updates the display values
    
    var is_dead = enemy_scene.take_damage(P_team.monster_invetory[0].attack) # Checks if dead
    if is_dead:
        current_state = GameState.WON
    elif !is_dead:
        current_state = GameState.ENEMYTURN
        enemy_attack() # Here is where the enemy decides what to do, for now it only attacks
        
func enemy_attack(): # Attacks the player
    print("Enemy attacking")
    P_team.monster_invetory[0].take_damage(enemy_scene.attack) # Calls the function to take damage
    yield(get_tree().create_timer(2), "timeout") #Wait for 2 seconds
    Player_battle_scene(P_team.monster_invetory[0]) #This updates the display values
    
    var is_dead = P_team.monster_invetory[0].take_damage(enemy_scene.attack) # Checks if dead
    if is_dead:
        current_state = GameState.LOST
    elif !is_dead:
        current_state = GameState.PLAYERTURN
        #player_attack()

func _on_Attack_button_pressed():
    if current_state != GameState.PLAYERTURN:
        return
    player_attack()
    #check_speed()
```

Comment: The easiest thing I would imagine is creating a list of all objects that can attack and then sorting that list in descending order equal to the speed. After you've done that you can just loop through the list and execute their attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### New Answer

*A state machine by any other name.*

You have states:

```
enum GameState {START, CHOICE, PLAYERTURN, ENEMYTURN, WON, LOST, CAPTURE}
var current_state = GameState.START
```

We can make that more useful by turning `current_state` into a property and adding a `"state_changed"` signal:

```
signal state_changed()
enum GameState {START, CHOICE, PLAYERTURN, ENEMYTURN,WON, LOST, CAPTURE}
var current_state setget set_current_state
func set_current_state(new_value):
    current_state = new_value
    emit_signal("state_changed")
```

Now, every time we set `self.current_state`, it will trigger the signal. And of course we can connect to it.

So we can do this:

```
func _ready():
    self.connect("state_changed", self, "_on_state_changed")
    self.current_state = GameState.START

func _on_state_changed():
    match current_state:
        GameState.START:
            _start()
        GameState.CHOICE:
            _choice()
        GameState.PLAYERTURN:
            _player_turn()
        GameState.ENEMYTURN:
            _enemy_turn()
        GameState.LOST:
            _lost()
        GameState.CAPTURE:
            _capture()
```

Why not put `_on_state_changed` directly in `set_current_state`? Because the signal is asynchronous. *Also, you don't have to handle them all on this script. You may even have a script for each state.*

Alright, let us start making those functions:

START:

```
func _start():
    # initalization stuff
    self.current_state = GameState.CHOICE
```

CHOICE:

```
func _choice():
    # We have to wait for the button press, we do nothing here
    pass
    
func _on_Attack_button_pressed():
    if current_state != GameState.CHOICE:
        return

    if _player_speed() > _enemy_speed(): # Checks which monster is faster
        self.current_state = GameState.PLAYERTURN
    else:
        self.current_state = GameState.ENEMYTURN
```

With some definition of `_player_speed` and `_enemy_speed`.

PLAYER_TURN and ENEMY_TURN:

```
var enemy_attk = false
var player_attk = false

func _player_turn():
    yield(_player_attack(), "completed")
    if _enemy_is_dead():
        self.current_state = GameState.WON
    else:
        if enemy_attk:
            player_attk = false
            enemy_attk = false
            self.current_state = GameState.CHOICE
        else:
            player_attk = true
            self.current_state = GameState.ENEMYTURN

func _enemy_turn():
    yield(_enemy_attack(), "completed")
    if _player_is_dead():
        self.current_state = GameState.LOST
    else:
        if player_attk:
            player_attk = false
            enemy_attk = false
            self.current_state = GameState.CHOICE
        else:
            enemy_attk = true
            self.current_state = GameState.PLAYERTURN
```

With some definition of `_player_is_dead`, `_enemy_is_dead`, `_player_attack` and `_enemy_attack`.

WON, LOST and CAPTURE:

```
func _lost():
    # whatever happens
    pass
    
func _won():
    # whatever happens
    pass
    
func _capture():
    # whatever happens
    pass
```

*I have no idea.*

---

Now, let us merge PLAYERTURN, ENEMYTURN into a new BATTLE state. Update the enum:

```
enum GameState {START, CHOICE, BATTLE, WON, LOST, CAPTURE}
```

Update the match statement:

```
func _on_state_changed():
    match current_state:
        GameState.START:
            _start()
        GameState.CHOICE:
            _choice()
        GameState.BATTLE:
            _battle()
        GameState.LOST:
            _lost()
        GameState.CAPTURE:
            _capture()
```

When the button is pressed, we simply change to BATTLE:

```
func _on_Attack_button_pressed():
    if current_state != GameState.CHOICE:
        return

    self.current_state = GameState.BATTLE
```

And now the main act:

```
func _battle():
    if _player_speed() > _enemy_speed(): # Checks which monster is faster
        yield(_player_attack(), "completed")
        if _enemy_is_dead():
            self.current_state = GameState.WON
        else:
            yield(_enemy_attack(), "completed")
            if _player_is_dead():
                self.current_state = GameState.LOST
            else:
                self.current_state = GameState.CHOICE
    else:
        yield(_enemy_attack(), "completed")
        if _player_is_dead():
            self.current_state = GameState.LOST
        else:
            yield(_player_attack(), "completed")
            if _enemy_is_dead():
                self.current_state = GameState.WON
            else:
                self.current_state = GameState.CHOICE
```

---

Let us talk about working with objects. First of all, have references to them. You already have `enemy_scene`, let us use it. We need to add a counter part `player_scene`.

```
onready var player_scene = P_team.monster_invetory[0]
```

By the way, if I were you, I'd add a script to `EnemyPos` and `PlayerPos` so I can do this:

```
$EnemyPos.update_view(enemy_scene)
$PlayerPos.update_view(player_scene)
```

Now, START can look like this:

```
func _start():
    _update_view()
    print("Battle started")
    yield(get_tree().create_timer(0.2), "timeout")
    self.current_state = GameState.CHOICE

func _update_view():
    $PlayerPos.update(player_scene)
    $EnemyPos.update(enemy_scene)
```

A suggestion: Add a "health_changed" signal to those scenes, and connect it to `$PlayerPos` or `$EnemyPos` respectively, so they can update automatically. *In fact, we could use that signal to handle when the monsters die.*

The attack is an issue, because these objects do not know their target. Will worry about that later.

Now update BATTLE to work with `player_scene` and `enemy_scene`:

```
func _battle():
    if player_scene.speed > enemy_scene.speed:
        yield(attack(player_scene, enemy_scene), "completed")
        if enemy_scene.current_health == 0:
            self.current_state = GameState.WON
        else:
            yield(attack(enemy_scene, player_scene), "completed")
            if player_scene.current_health == 0:
                self.current_state = GameState.LOST
            else:
                self.current_state = GameState.CHOICE
    else:
        yield(attack(enemy_scene, player_scene), "completed")
        if player_scene.current_health == 0:
            self.current_state = GameState.LOST
        else:
            yield(attack(player_scene, enemy_scene), "completed")
            if enemy_scene.current_health == 0:
                self.current_state = GameState.WON
            else:
                self.current_state = GameState.CHOICE

func attack(attacker, target):
    print(attacker.name, " attacking")
    target.take_damage(attacker.attack) # Calls the function to take damage
    yield(get_tree().create_timer(2), "timeout") #Wait for 2 seconds
    _update_view()
```

*Please note that with a "health_changed" signal this code is much simpler. In that you won't have to handle winning and losing conditions on `_battle`, nor call `_update_view` from `attack`.*

Finally, we can write a version that puts them in an array:

```
func _battle():
    var participants = [player_scene, enemy_scene]
    participants.sort_custom(self, "check_speed")
    for attacker in participants:
        var target = _choose_target(attacker, participants)
        yield(attack(attacker, target), "completed")

        if player_scene.current_health == 0:
            self.current_state = GameState.LOST
            return
        if enemy_scene.current_health == 0:
            self.current_state = GameState.WON
            return

    self.current_state = GameState.CHOICE

func check_speed(a, b):
    return a.speed > b.speed:

func _choose_target(attacker, participants):
    for participant in participants:
        if participant == attacker:
            continue

        return participant
```

*Again, this would be simpler with a "health_changed" signal.*

This would still require some modification to fully support more than two monsters:

- To win it would check if all enemy monsters are dead, not just the one.
- To lose it would check if all ally monsters are dead, not just the one.
- When choosing target make sure it picks of the appropriate team considering the attacker. *You may also consider given control to the player to choose targets.*

You can, of course, keep the array outside of `_battle` and remove participants when they die. Then checking if all enemy monsters are dead, is actually checking if all the remaining monsters are allies (and viceversa). Which you could do by keeping the count of how many ally or enemy monsters are there, and decrement it as they die. *And you can do that connecting to the "health_changed" signal.*

---

Ah, yes, a version that allows a monster to attack multiple times according to its speed. You will need a new attribute on these scenes. I'll call it `exhaustion`, it should be `0` at the start of the battle.

```
func _battle():
    var participants = [player_scene, enemy_scene]
    var player_attacked = false
    while (true):
        var attacker = get_next(participants)

        if player_scene == attacker:
            if player_attacked:
                # It is time for the player to attack again.
                # Return control to the player.
                self.current_state = GameState.CHOICE
                return
            else:
                player_attacked = true

        var target = _choose_target(attacker, participants)

        yield(attack(attacker, target), "completed")
        attacker.exhaustion += 1.0 / attacker.speed # <--

        if player_scene.current_health == 0:
            self.current_state = GameState.LOST
            return
        if enemy_scene.current_health == 0:
            self.current_state = GameState.WON
            return

func get_next(participants):
    participants.sort_custom(self, "check_order")
    return participants[0]

func check_order(a, b):
    if a.exhaustion < b.exhaustion:
        return true

    if a.exhaustion == b.exhaustion:
        return a.speed > b.speed:

    return false
```

As you can see here, the rule is that the monster with less `exhaustion` goes first. If two monsters have the same `exhaustion`, the one with more `speed` goes first. And every time a monster attacks, its `exhaustion` is incremented. By how much? The inverse of `speed`. Thus monsters with less `speed` get exhausted quicker, and monsters with more `speed` get exhausted slower. As a consequence, if a monster has more `speed` than the other, it will end up doing multiple attacks for each one that the first one does.

**Note**: I called it "exhaustion" just so you have some intuition of how the value changes. However, it is important that this is not kept from battle to battle, it must be reset to `0`. If you imagine an exhausted monster vs a not exhausted one, the not exhausted one will get a lot of attacks in before the other one can do anything.

We need to keep track if the player attacked, as I mentioned in the original answer, to break the loop.

---

### Original answer

It depends on how exactly you want Speed to work, I'll only show the simplest approach. But first let us start at a base line.

Let us say, that disregarding speed, the player attacks, then the monster attacks, and then it waits for next input.

That means doing this something like this:

```
func _on_Attack_button_pressed():
    # ...
    player_attack()
    enemy_attack()
```

Except those function `yield`. So we are going to need this:

```
func _on_Attack_button_pressed():
    # ...
    yield(player_attack(), "completed")
    yield(enemy_attack(), "completed")
```

The reason is that a function which yields returns a [`GDScriptFunctionState`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_gdscriptfunctionstate.html).

Documentation on says `GDScriptFunctionState`:

> Calling @GDScript.yield within a function will cause that function to yield and return its current state as an object of this type

Here I'm using the `"completed"` signal of `GDScriptFunctionState` as suggested in the documentation on [Coroutines & signals](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#coroutines-signals):

> If you're unsure whether a function may yield or not, or whether it may yield multiple times, you can yield to the completed signal conditionally

---

Now, the simplest way to have "speed" work is to treat speed as turn order. Similar to D&D initiative. That means that all we do is sort those operations according to speed. So you do something like this:

```
func _on_Attack_button_pressed():
    # ...
    if player_goes_first():
        yield(player_attack(), "completed")
        yield(enemy_attack(), "completed")
    else:
        yield(enemy_attack(), "completed")
        yield(player_attack(), "completed")
```

Giving your code, I'm guessing `player_goes_first` will simply return `P_team.monster_invetory[0].speed > enemy_scene.speed`. See [Functions](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html?#functions).

We could also write it like this:

```
func _on_Attack_button_pressed():
    # ...
    if player_speed() > enemy_speed():
        yield(player_attack(), "completed")
        yield(enemy_attack(), "completed")
    else:
        yield(enemy_attack(), "completed")
        yield(player_attack(), "completed")
```

Where `player_speed` and `enemy_speed` are functions that return the appropriate values.

If you needed three participants, you can imagine the code ([something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13040256/402022)).

---

However, your code would benefit from using objects with a `speed` property and an `attack` method (Those objects may or may not be nodes, see [Classes](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html?#classes)).

If you have objects, it would be it easier to support more participants:

- Put the participants in an array.
- Sort them by `speed`, with [`sort_custom`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_array.html#class-array-method-sort-custom).
- Iterate over the array, and call `attack` on each one.

Another approach is to have a `get_next` function that returns the next object on which to call `attack`. Then call `get_next` on a loop. You would have a variable to keep track of whether or not the player has attacked (by checking if the what you got from `get_next` is the player object), and stop before the loop player attacks twice (since the user is supposed to press the button to attack again).

Using a `get_next` function would allow for more complex logic. For example, have a participant attack multiple times according to its `speed`.

Comment: Sorry should of mentioned I wanted it to be like Pokémon where the higher speed goes first I see you wrote something about I will take a look when I get home, thanks!

Comment: Hello Theraot I want to implement the last bit where you talk about using an array and sorting it by speed, could you give a rough code sample, this is what I have changed based on what you have said, This includes the whole script but the most important functions are labeled accordingly https://pasteall.org/ZLLN

Comment: I should also mention the player monster is already in an array though it's a Team array the enemy is by it's self but will be in a array called enemy team, I assume I have to make a new array and add the enemy and currently on screen monster to it and do some sort of comparison, how would I do the attacking?

Comment: @Dragon20C If I were to implement that, Id probably move code to another script. Besides, you have added a `battle_mode` function, which uses `yield` (because it uses `enemy_attack` and `player_attack`. As such it would also need to be called in the same fashion. However, why are you making it recursive? You can do the `is_dead` check in `_on_Attack_button_pressed` and then you can merge it with `battle_mode`. Anyway, bottom line: I'd change a lot fo the code.

Comment: @Dragon20C when I see `player_attack` and `enemy_attack` and how similar they are, I think there should be a class with an `attack` method that does that. It would also have `speed`. And when I see `Player_battle_scene` and `Enemy_battle_scene`, that logic should be on `EnemyPos` and `PlayerPos`. And then I think, that can be the class with `attack` and `speed` I was thinking of. And those would be the objects in the array I was talking about in the answer. And I'd probably add custom signals to them, and connect them to this script.

Comment: I see what I can do, the reason the code is a mess I am trying to figure it out, You mentioned something being recursive, I think you are talking about how it can call attacks again, I did it this way because I couldnt figure it out to play both the enemys and players attacks in a order, for example if the enemy attacks it doesnt switch to the player which the battle_mode does, and the monsters are resources that have a speed, attack, defend etc in them so i can just call what ever variable I want, you also mentioned the functions being to similar, do you want me to just make one function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231706/discussion-between-dragon20c-and-theraot).