# Converting from Source-based Indices to Destination-based Indices

Tags: c, math, sse, simd, avx2

I'm using AVX2 instructions in some C code.

The [VPERMD](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/VPERMD.html) instruction takes two 8-integer vectors `a` and `idx` and generates a third one, `dst`, by permuting `a` based on `idx`. This seems equivalent to `dst[i] = a[idx[i]] for i in 0..7`. I'm calling this source based, because the move is indexed based on the source.

However, I have my calculated indices in destination based form. This is natural for setting an array, and is equivalent to `dst[idx[i]] = a[i] for i in 0..7`.

How can I convert from source-based form to destination-based form? An example test case is:

```
{2 1 0 5 3 4 6 7}    source-based form. 
{2 1 0 4 5 3 6 7}    destination-based equivalent
```

For this conversion, I'm staying in ymm registers, so that means that destination-based solutions don't work. Even if I were to insert each separately, since it only operates on constant indexes, you can't just set them.

Comment: That's just the classic "permutation inversion", `dst[src[i]] = i`

Comment: Right. But your code requires the ability to set in a destination-based manner. Since I'm operating in AVX2 registers. I can't do that. I have working C code that does it almost exactly as you say, but I need to be able to transform the indices without being able to do a destination-based permutation, like you suggest.

Comment: Your `a[i] = a[idx[i]] for i in 0..7` didn't correctly describe VPERMD's operation, because it implied that changes to `a` would feed back into the `a[idx[i]]` for later elements.  e.g. The original `a[0]` would always be destroyed right away, unless `idx[0] = 0`.  I think your example is still sane after my edit to correct that bug (or was assuming that behaviour the whole time).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I did understand the behavior, but I didn't describe it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're implicitly saying that you can't modify your code to calculate source-based indices in the first place?  I can't think of anything you can do with x86 SIMD, other than AVX512 scatter instructions that take dst-based indices.  (But those are not very fast on current CPUs, even compared to gather loads.  https://uops.info/)

Storing to memory, inverting, and reloading a vector might actually be best.  (Or transferring to integer registers directly, not through memory, maybe after a vextracti128 / packusdw so you only need two 64-bit transfers from vector to integer regs: movq and pextrq).

But anyway, then use them as indices to store a counter into an array in memory, and reload that as a vector.  This is still slow and ugly, and includes a store-forwarding failure delay.  So it's probably worth your while to change your index-generating code to generate source-based shuffle vectors if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks for the idea with the scatter operation. I added an example as answer.

Answer (score 1):

To benchmark the solution, I modified the code from my other answer to compare the performance of the scatter instruction (`USE_SCATTER` defined) with a store and sequential permute (`USE_SCATTER` undefined). I had to copy the result back to the permutation pattern `perm` in order to prevent the compiler from optimizing the loop body away:

```
#ifdef TEST_SCATTER
  #define REPEATS 1000000001
  #define USE_SCATTER
  
  __m512i ident = _mm512_set_epi32(15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0);
  __m512i perm  = _mm512_set_epi32(7,9,3,0,5,8,13,11,4,2,15,1,12,6,10,14);  
  uint32_t outA[16] __attribute__ ((aligned(64)));
  uint32_t id[16], in[16];
  _mm512_storeu_si512(id, ident);
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) printf("%2d ", id[i]); puts("");
  _mm512_storeu_si512(in, perm);
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) printf("%2d ", in[i]); puts("");
#ifdef USE_SCATTER
  puts("scatter");
  for (long t = 0; t < REPEATS; t++) {
    _mm512_i32scatter_epi32(outA, perm, ident, 4);
    perm = _mm512_load_si512(outA);
  }
#else
  puts("store & permute");
  uint32_t permA[16] __attribute__ ((aligned(64)));
  for (long t = 0; t < REPEATS; t++) {
    _mm512_store_si512(permA, perm);
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) outA[permA[i]] = i;
    perm = _mm512_load_si512(outA);    
  }
#endif
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) printf("%2d ", outA[i]); puts("");

#endif
```

Here's the output for the two cases (using the builtin `time` command of `tcsh`, the `u` output is user-space time in seconds):

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
14 10  6 12  1 15  2  4 11 13  8  5  0  3  9  7 
store & permute
12  4  6 13  7 11  2 15 10 14  1  8  3  9  0  5 
10.765u 0.001s 0:11.22 95.9%    0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w

 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
14 10  6 12  1 15  2  4 11 13  8  5  0  3  9  7 
scatter
12  4  6 13  7 11  2 15 10 14  1  8  3  9  0  5 
10.740u 0.000s 0:11.19 95.9%    0+0k 40+0io 0pf+0w
```

The runtime is about the same (Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2125 CPU @ 4.00GHz, clang++-6.0, `-O3 -funroll-loops -march=native`). I checked the assembly code generated. With `USE_SCATTER` defined, the compiler generates `vpscatterdd` instructions, without it generates complex code using `vpextrd`, `vpextrq`, and `vpextracti32x4`.

---

Edit: I was worried that the compiler may have found a specific solution for the fixed permutation pattern I used. So I replaced it with a randomly generated pattern from `std::random_shuffe()`, but the time measurements are about the same.

---

Edit: Following the comment by Peter Cordes,  I wrote a modified benchmark that hopefully measures something like throughput:

```
  #define REPEATS 1000000
  #define ARRAYSIZE 1000
  #define USE_SCATTER
  
  std::srand(unsigned(std::time(0)));
  // build array with random permutations
  uint32_t permA[ARRAYSIZE][16] __attribute__ ((aligned(64)));
  for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++)
    _mm512_store_si512(permA[i], randPermZMM());
  // vector register
  __m512i perm;
#ifdef USE_SCATTER
  puts("scatter");
  __m512i ident = _mm512_set_epi32(15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0);
  for (long t = 0; t < REPEATS; t++)
    for (long i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++) {
      perm = _mm512_load_si512(permA[i]);
      _mm512_i32scatter_epi32(permA[i], perm, ident, 4);
    }
#else
  uint32_t permAsingle[16] __attribute__ ((aligned(64)));
  puts("store & permute");
  for (long t = 0; t < REPEATS; t++)
    for (long i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++) {
      perm = _mm512_load_si512(permA[i]);
      _mm512_store_si512(permAsingle, perm);
      uint32_t *permAVec = permA[i];
      for (int e = 0; e < 16; e++)
    permAVec[permAsingle[e]] = e;
    }
#endif
  FILE *f = fopen("testperm.dat", "w");
  fwrite(permA, ARRAYSIZE, 64, f);
  fclose(f);
```

I use an array of permutation patterns which are modified sequentially without dependencies.

These are the results:

```
scatter
4.241u 0.002s 0:04.26 99.5% 0+0k 80+128io 0pf+0w

store & permute
5.956u 0.002s 0:05.97 99.6% 0+0k 80+128io 0pf+0w
```

So throughput is better when using the scatter command.

Comment: With the reload of output as the permutation for the next iteration, you're measuring latency, not throughput.  Including the store-forwarding stall from doing the reload right away.  That might reflect some use-cases, but measuring throughput might be interesting, too.

Comment: That's 10.765u = user-space seconds, right? Not 10.765u = microseconds.  10 sec is plenty long to hide any warm-up effects and other overhead so that's fine.

Comment: @PeterCordes: What would be a code modification to measure throughput? Apply this to an array of (randomly generated) permutation patterns? / The time measurements are from the `tcsh` builtin `time` command and the `u` time is user space time in seconds.

Comment: Easy in asm: run the instructions *without* feeding the result back as a dependency for the next iteration.  So out-of-order exec can work its magic and overlap multiple iterations.  Getting a C compiler to emit asm like that may require some careful use of `volatile` vars to force a load, or `asm("" : "+x"(vector))` to forget anything it knows about the value of a vector variable.  e.g. like `Benchmark::DoNotOptimize` or various other tricks.  Then you check the generated asm to make sure it's looks realistic for what you want to measure.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I included a modified benchmark in my answer. Do you think that is related to throughput?

Comment: Yeah, independent work on independent array elements is throughput-dependent, letting OoO exec hide latency.  Your array is small enough that it will fit in L2 cache, but 1000 * 64 bytes is larger than 32kiB L1d.  (Or even the 48kiB L1d on Ice Lake). 
 But it's small enough that page faults won't be a complicating factor.  You may *want* that to simulate the case where things aren't always hot in L1d, and updating pointers in a loop, so this is probably good.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in the opposite direction: destination indices were easy to compute, but source indices were required for the application of SIMD permute instructions. Here's a solution for AVX-512 using a scatter instruction as suggested by Peter Cordes; it should also apply to the opposite direction:

```
__m512i ident = _mm512_set_epi32(15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0);
__m512i perm  = _mm512_set_epi32(7,9,3,0,5,8,13,11,4,2,15,1,12,6,10,14);  
uint32_t id[16], in[16], out[16];
_mm512_storeu_si512(id, ident);
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) printf("%2d ", id[i]); puts("");
_mm512_storeu_si512(in, perm);
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) printf("%2d ", in[i]); puts("");
_mm512_i32scatter_epi32(out, perm, ident, 4);
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) printf("%2d ", out[i]); puts("");
```

An identity mapping `ident` is distributed to the `out` array according to the index pattern `perm`. The idea is basically the same as the one described for [inverting a permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group#Neutral_element_and_inverses). Here's the output:

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
14 10  6 12  1 15  2  4 11 13  8  5  0  3  9  7 
12  4  6 13  7 11  2 15 10 14  1  8  3  9  0  5
```

Note that I have permutations in the mathematical sense (no duplicates). With duplicates, the `out` store needs to be initialized since some elements could remain unwritten.

I also see no easy way to accomplish this within registers. I thought about cycling through the given permutation by repeatedly applying a permute instruction. As soon as the identity pattern is reached, the one before is the inverse permutation (this goes back to the idea by EOF on [unzip operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376193/sse-avx-equivalent-for-neon-vuzp)). However, the cycles can be long. The maximum number of cycles that may be required is given by [Landau's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function) which for 16 elements is 140, see this [table](https://oeis.org/A000793). I could show that it possible to shorten this to a maximum of 16 if the individual permutation subcycles are frozen as soon as they coincide with the identity elements. The shortens the average from 28 to 9 permute instructions for a test on random permutation patterns. However, it is still not an efficient solution (much slower than the scatter instruction in the throughput benchmark described in my other answer).

Comment: Have you benchmarked this against anything?  Scatter instructions are not very fast; IDK if that was a good suggestion I made 4 years ago.  But they're not terrible, and this might be better than any other option.  Certainly it's much worse than a shuffle if you *did* have the right kind of indices.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I added another answer with a benchmark. Apparently there's no performance advantage of using the scatter.