# Is there a SIMD intrinsics like scatter but between registers?

Tags: simd, sse, avx

So as far as I know there is _mm_shuffle_epi8 if you want to do

```
dst[i] = a[b[i]]
```

but my question is if there is a intrinsic that does

```
dst[b[i]] = a[i]
```

I want it to work with 16 elements of 8 bits (doesn't matter if it's signed or not)

I looked trough Intel Intrinsics Guide but didn't find anything there except permute and shuffle which seem close but I don't think they do dst[b[i]] = a[i]. I tried looking on web but I am not sure what to search. The only thing that I found out that I need "scatter" kind of "permutation" between simd registers.

Comment: No, all x86 shuffles use source indices, not destination.  I think that's the case on other ISAs as well (like AArch64 advsimd and PowerPC Altivec, although you mentioned `_mm_shuffle_epi8` so I assume you're most interested in x86).   Related: [Converting from Source-based Indices to Destination-based Indices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39260585)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way to scatter (and I don't expect we will ever have it (we have it with a memory destination but it's not great)) but what you *can* do, surprisingly, is invert a permutation. And then you can use that inverse-permutation to do a normal source-index-based shuffle. An obvious requirement for that to work is that there are no "collisions" where more than one element is sent to the same position (but what would that mean anyway).

Here is some AVX2 code, taken from [(Not) transposing a 16x16 bitmatrix](https://bitmath.blogspot.com/2023/04/not-transposing-16x16-bitmatrix.html) (which I also wrote), modified slightly so it takes and returns a `__m128i` directly. Just use `_mm_shuffle_epi8(a, invert_permutation_avx2(b))`.

```
__m256i nottranspose16x16(__m256i x)
{
    // exchange off-diagonal quadrants
    x = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(x, _mm256_setr_epi8(
        0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15,
        0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15));
    x = _mm256_permutex_epi64(x, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 1, 2, 0));
    x = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(x, _mm256_setr_epi8(
        0, 8, 1, 9, 2, 10, 3, 11, 4, 12, 5, 13, 6, 14, 7, 15,
        0, 8, 1, 9, 2, 10, 3, 11, 4, 12, 5, 13, 6, 14, 7, 15));
    // rotate every row by its y coordinate
    __m256i shifts = _mm256_setr_epi16(
        1 << 0, 1 << 1, 1 << 2, 1 << 3,
        1 << 4, 1 << 5, 1 << 6, 1 << 7,
        1 << 8, 1 << 9, 1 << 10, 1 << 11,
        1 << 12, 1 << 13, 1 << 14, 1 << 15);
    __m256i sll = _mm256_mullo_epi16(x, shifts);
    __m256i srl = _mm256_mulhi_epu16(x, shifts);
    x = _mm256_or_si256(sll, srl);
    // within each quadrant independently, 
    // rotate every column by its x coordinate
    __m256i x0, x1, m;
    // rotate by 4
    m = _mm256_set1_epi8(0x0F);
    x0 = _mm256_and_si256(x, m);
    x1 = _mm256_andnot_si256(m, _mm256_alignr_epi8(x, x, 8));
    x = _mm256_or_si256(x0, x1);
    // rotate by 2
    m = _mm256_set1_epi8(0x33);
    x0 = _mm256_and_si256(x, m);
    x1 = _mm256_andnot_si256(m, _mm256_alignr_epi8(x, x, 4));
    x = _mm256_or_si256(x0, x1);
    // rotate by 1
    m = _mm256_set1_epi8(0x55);
    x0 = _mm256_and_si256(x, m);
    x1 = _mm256_andnot_si256(m, _mm256_alignr_epi8(x, x, 2));
    x = _mm256_or_si256(x0, x1);
    return x;
}

__m128i invert_permutation_avx2(__m128i p)
{
    __m256i v = _mm256_cvtepu8_epi16(p);
    // indexes to masks
    v = _mm256_or_si256(v, _mm256_slli_epi64(v, 8));
    v = _mm256_add_epi8(v, _mm256_set1_epi16(0xF878));
    __m256i m = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(_mm256_setr_epi8(
        1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128,
        1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128,
        1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128,
        1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128), v);
    // ???
    m = nottranspose16x16(m);
    // masks to indexes
    __m256i deBruijn = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_mulhi_epu16(m, _mm256_set1_epi16(0x9AF0)), _mm256_set1_epi16(0x000F));
    __m128i i = _mm_packs_epi16(_mm256_castsi256_si128(deBruijn), _mm256_extracti128_si256(deBruijn, 1));
    i = _mm_shuffle_epi8(_mm_setr_epi8(
        0, 1, 2, 5, 3, 9, 6, 11, 15, 4, 8, 10, 14, 7, 13, 12), i);
    // un-mess-up the indexes
    i = _mm_sub_epi8(i, _mm_setr_epi8(0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 8, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9));
    i = _mm_and_si128(i, _mm_set1_epi8(0x0F));
    i = _mm_shuffle_epi8(i, _mm_setr_epi8(0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 8, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9));
    return i;
}
```

This would be easier to do with GFNI (since GF2P8AFFINEQB is very useful for transposing bit-matrices), especially if we also have AVX512 for some other operations that AVX2 has some trouble with. Based on the tags of this question I chose not to use those newer instruction set extensions.

Answer (score 3):

There is no efficient way to do this as there are no x86 instructions (as of the time of this answer) that permute vector register values based on the target element indices. However, if you have many elements that you need to shuffle according to the same mask, you can create a source-based shuffle mask that has the same effect as the target-based mask and use it repeatedly on your data.

Here's an example:

```
//! Creates a source-based shuffle mask from a target-based one
__m128i create_shuffle_mask(__m128i mm_target_indices)
{
    __m128i mm_res = _mm_setzero_si128();
    // Set mm_res to all-ones by default. This will result in zeroing
    // the elements that are not specified in the target indices.
    mm_res = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(mm_res, mm_res);

    const __m128i mm_lowest_byte_mask = _mm_setr_epi32(0xFF, 0, 0, 0);
    const __m128i mm_lowest_byte_7 = _mm_setr_epi32(7, 0, 0, 0);
    const __m128i mm_lowest_byte_8 = _mm_setr_epi32(8, 0, 0, 0);
    const __m128i mm_1 = _mm_set1_epi8(1);
    __m128i mm_i = _mm_setzero_si128();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    {
        // Target index, [0; 7]
        __m128i mm_lowest_index =
            _mm_and_si128(mm_target_indices, mm_lowest_byte_7);
        // A bit that indicates whether the index is in range [8; 15]
        __m128i mm_use_hi = _mm_and_si128(mm_target_indices, mm_lowest_byte_8);

        // Multiply the index by 8 and shift the byte mask into position
        // in the lower half of the vector
        __m128i mm_byte_mask = _mm_sll_epi64(mm_lowest_byte_mask,
            _mm_slli_epi32(mm_lowest_index, 3));
        if (!_mm_testz_si128(mm_use_hi, mm_use_hi))
        {
            // Shift the byte mask into the upper half of the vector
            mm_byte_mask = _mm_slli_si128(mm_byte_mask, 8);
        }

        // Put the index into the final mask
        mm_res = _mm_blendv_epi8(mm_res, mm_i, mm_byte_mask);

        mm_i = _mm_add_epi8(mm_i, mm_1);
        mm_target_indices = _mm_srli_si128(mm_target_indices, 1);
    }

    return mm_res;
}

__m128i mm_data = _mm_setr_epi8(
    100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107,
    108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115);
__m128i mm_target_indices = _mm_setr_epi8(
    0, 15, 1, 14, 2, 13, 3, 12, 4, 11, 5, 10, 6, 9, 7, 8);
__m128i mm_shuffle_mask = create_shuffle_mask(mm_target_indices);
__m128i mm_res = _mm_shuffle_epi8(mm_data, mm_shuffle_mask);
// mm_res = { 100, 102, 104, 106, 108, 110, 112, 114,
//            115, 113, 111, 109, 107, 105, 103, 101 }
```

[Live on Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b48fb7ddbbbc1a7c)

It should be noted that unlike the source-based masks, which write into every target element exactly once, target-based masks can skip target elements or write more than once. This means you'll have to decide on the behavior you want in these cases. The code above creates a shuffle mask that will zero target elements that were not mentioned in the target-based mask, and use the last mentioned element (i.e. the highest-position element) in the target-based mask if the target element is written more than once.