# Algorithm to Sort a List of n Number of Items by Comparing them Against One Another in Pairs

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I will try to be specific as possible as I can't find anything on this through the Google gods.

I have a list of 10 movies. I would like to display the movies in pairs. The user picks their favorite of the two. The next pair is displayed. The user picks their favorite of those two, so on and so on until I can faithfully output the list in their order of preference from 1-10.

I'm doing this in Javascript, but even just a way to do it that is language agnostic would be great. No need to worry about syntax or UI stuff.

With three movies it's pretty easy (initial order of movies and order of pairs shouldn't matter):

```
1.sw
2.esb
3.rotj

example 1
1vs2: winner = 2
2vs3: winner = 2
1vs3: winner = 1
Sorted List: 2,1,3

example 2
1vs3: winner = 1
1vs2: winner = 2 
2vs3: winner = 2
Sorted List: 2,1,3
```

First time posting so if I need to be more specific, need to have exact syntax, etc., please don't hesitate to let me know.

Comment: You should provide some code, and explain what you can't figure out with it.

Comment: Your example looks a lot like a [sorting network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network). [Here's a link to an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789530) that shows a sorting network for 6 items. As you can see, sorting gets to be real tedious for the user as the number of items increases (it takes twelve questions to sort 6 items).

Comment: Are you comparing every pair? Or do you stop if you have some transitive property? (i.e. if a > b, and b > c, do you ask if a > c?) Assuming you ask for every pair, you can do any comparison sort. You could store the votes in a map like `{'1:2': 1}` (1 vs 2 = 1) to look up the result of each comparison. Keep in mind the results may not be deterministic if you have cycles in your comparisons.

Comment: Thanks @user3386109, that helped set my expectations.

Comment: @ryansilva, I wasn't trying to have a transitive property, but I now see how that could have decreased my number of choices significantly. In future versions, I'll definitely try that. I did do the votes, but as a key/value pair on each movie. I'll try the match map in the next iteration. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum number of comparisons required to sort 10 items is 22. (See https://oeis.org/A036604). Do you really think your users will suffer through 22 "which movie do you like better?" questions? And do you honestly believe that the result will be useful? You'll have many cases where a user will say that he liked movie A better than B, and B better than C, but he liked movie C better than he liked movie A. So now you have the problem that:

```
A > B
B > C
C > A
```

And there's no reasonable way to resolve that conflict.

In short, your user interface is flawed. You can try to build it, but your users won't like it and your results will not be reliable.

A better interface would be to list the 10 movies and allow the users to arrange them in order of preference. Or let the user rate the movies on a scale from 1 to 5. But expecting users to answer 22 questions and get a complete ordering is a fool's errand.

Comment: Upvoted because of your link to oeis, which lead me to the Ford-Johnson insertion merge sort that I had not previously known.  However I believe that as bad a UI as it is, figuring out how to write it is a *really* good exercise in understanding async in JS.  It is a worthwhile programming problem.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I appreciate your candor. The exercise was really to deep dive if there was a better way to do it, but because of your point, the only real way to do is to present them all possibilities which shot it up to 45 steps. The original game was to sort Top 100 movies. Doing it that way resulted in 4,590 options. Think I'll switch it up to do elimination instead. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is easy.  We have a ton of sorting algorithms that will work with `O(n log(n))` comparisons.  For instance mergesort:

```
// Split the array into halves and merge them recursively 
function mergeSort (arr) {
  if (arr.length === 1) {
    // return once we hit an array with a single item
    return arr
  }

  const middle = Math.floor(arr.length / 2) // get the middle item of the array rounded down
  const left = arr.slice(0, middle) // items on the left side
  const right = arr.slice(middle) // items on the right side

  return merge(
    mergeSort(left),
    mergeSort(right)
  )
}

// compare the arrays item by item and return the concatenated result
function merge (left, right) {
  let result = []
  let indexLeft = 0
  let indexRight = 0

  while (indexLeft < left.length && indexRight < right.length) {
    if (left[indexLeft] < right[indexRight]) {
      result.push(left[indexLeft])
      indexLeft++
    } else {
      result.push(right[indexRight])
      indexRight++
    }
  }

  return result.concat(left.slice(indexLeft)).concat(right.slice(indexRight))
}
```

So in principle you need to simply replace `left[indexLeft] < right[indexRight]` with an arbitrary comparison function that asks the user, gets an answer, and then continues.

Now there is a catch.  The catch is that you need to make this code asynchronous.  When you go to ask the user, you need to ask the user, then return to inside your code.  If you're using node at the console, then you can do this with [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await).  If you are not, then you'll need to figure out how to do it with promises.  Modifying `mergeSort` is easy, just make the end into:

```
  return Promise.all([mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right)]
      ).then(function (values) {return merge(values[0], values[1])});
```

The trick is in turning the loop inside of `merge` into a function that takes the current state of your iteration, and returns a promise that asks the question, then either returns the final sorted array, or returns a promise that handles the next iteration.

Since this looks like homework, whose whole purpose is to make you face that mental challenge, I'll leave my answer off here.  Fair warning, I gave you a hint about how to do it, but if you're just learning about async code your head is SUPPOSED to spin as you figure it out.

Comment: Thank you so much. It will take me a while to wrap my head around the logic. I was able to solve the async part by using a simple counter that incremented each trip back to the code. Not async, but worked :)

Answer (score 0):

To determine all possible combinations from your array try the following loop. Assuming order does not matter and we do not want repeats:

```
  var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
  var arr_count = arr.length
  var combinations_array = []

  for (i = 0; i < arr_count; i++) { 
    var combinations = arr_count - (i+1)
    for (y = 0; y < combinations; y++) { 
      combination = [arr[i],arr[(combinations - y)]];
      combinations_array.push(combination);
    }
  }
```

In your example I'd pass Movie ID's into arr then iterate through the combinations_array to determine which combination of movies should be displayed next.

Comment: This helped a lot to be able to visualize the number of comparisons I was going to need. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

To produce a list of pairs, I would use a nested loop like this:

```
var items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
    result = [],
    x = 0,
    y = 0;

for (x = items.length; x--;)
{
  for(y = x; y--;)
  {
    result.push({ a: items[x], b: items[y] });
  }
}

console.debug(result);
```

The second loop is initialised from the outer loops incrementor so that you don't end up with duplicates.

Once you have the pairs, you should be able to build the ui from that.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This helped a lot to be able to visualize the number of comparisons I was going to need. Thanks.