# Understand efficient implementation of median filter with SSE2 / SSSE3 Instruction Set

Tags: c++, image-processing, sse, median, sorting-network

I'm recently stuck on understanding some legacy codes about median filter, it is totally implemented by SSE2 Instruction Set. My task is to improve its efficiency based on the legacy codes, which are as follows:

```cpp
/* sort pixel to acquire median value quickly. */
inline void sortSwap(__m128& a, __m128& b)
{
    __m128 temp = a;
    a = _mm_min_ps(a, b);
    b = _mm_max_ps(temp, b);
}

void medianDispOpt(float* dispImg, float* destDisp, const uint16_t width, const uint16_t height)
{
    float* dispImgTemp = destDisp;

    float* line1 = dispImg;
    float* line2 = dispImg + width;
    float* line3 = dispImg + 2 * width;

    float* end = dispImg + width*height;

    destDisp += width;
    __m128 lastMedian = _mm_setzero_ps();

    do {
        const __m128 line1_reg = _mm_load_ps(line1);
        const __m128 line1_reg_next = _mm_load_ps(line1 + 4);
        __m128 store0 = line1_reg;
        __m128 store1 = _mm_castsi128_ps(_mm_alignr_epi8(_mm_castps_si128(line1_reg_next), _mm_castps_si128(line1_reg), 4));
        __m128 store2 = _mm_castsi128_ps(_mm_alignr_epi8(_mm_castps_si128(line1_reg_next), _mm_castps_si128(line1_reg), 8));

        const __m128 line2_reg = _mm_load_ps(line2);
        const __m128 line2_reg_next = _mm_load_ps(line2 + 4);
        __m128 store3 = line2_reg;
        __m128 store4 = _mm_castsi128_ps(_mm_alignr_epi8(_mm_castps_si128(line2_reg_next), _mm_castps_si128(line2_reg), 4));
        __m128 store5 = _mm_castsi128_ps(_mm_alignr_epi8(_mm_castps_si128(line2_reg_next), _mm_castps_si128(line2_reg), 8));

        const __m128 line3_reg = _mm_load_ps(line3);
        const __m128 line3_reg_next = _mm_load_ps(line3 + 4);
        __m128 store6 = line3_reg;
        __m128 store7 = _mm_castsi128_ps(_mm_alignr_epi8(_mm_castps_si128(line3_reg_next), _mm_castps_si128(line3_reg), 4));
        __m128 store8 = _mm_castsi128_ps(_mm_alignr_epi8(_mm_castps_si128(line3_reg_next), _mm_castps_si128(line3_reg), 8));

        // find median
        sortSwap(store1, store2); 
        sortSwap(store4, store5); 
        sortSwap(store7, store8);
        sortSwap(store0, store1); 
        sortSwap(store3, store4); 
        sortSwap(store6, store7);
        sortSwap(store1, store2); 
        sortSwap(store4, store5); 
        sortSwap(store7, store8);
        sortSwap(store0, store3); 
        sortSwap(store5, store8); 
        sortSwap(store4, store7);       
        sortSwap(store3, store6); 
        sortSwap(store1, store4); 
        sortSwap(store2, store5);       
        sortSwap(store4, store7); 
        sortSwap(store4, store2); 
        sortSwap(store6, store4);
        sortSwap(store4, store2);

        const __m128i c = _mm_alignr_epi8(_mm_castps_si128(store4), _mm_castps_si128(lastMedian), 12);
        _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)destDisp, c);
        lastMedian = store4;

        destDisp += 4; line1 += 4; line2 += 4; line3 += 4;

    } while (line3 + 4 + 4 <= end);

    memcpy(dispImgTemp, dispImg, sizeof(float)*(width + 1));
    memcpy(dispImgTemp + width*height - width - 1 - 3, dispImg + width*height - width - 1 - 3, sizeof(float)*(width + 1 + 3));
}
```

the **input image** `dispImg` is of `width * height` with float pixel, the image data array is arranged by the image row, and each row is compactly laid(i.e. no redundant pixels between rows).
Now, suppose the `line1_reg,line1_reg_next,line2_reg,line2_reg_next,line3_reg,line3_reg_next` of first three rows are briefly represented by following numbers:

```
line1_reg= {0 1 2 3}, line1_reg_next = {4 5 6 7}
line2_reg= {8 9 10 11}, line2_reg_next = {12 13 14 15}
line3_reg= {16 17 18 19}, line2_reg_next = {20 21 22 23}
```

so `storen`s are:

```
store0 = {0,1,2,3}, store1={1,2,3,4},store2={2,3,4,5}
store3 = {8,9,10,11}, store4={9,10,11,12},store5={10,11,12,13}
store6 = {16,17,18,19}, store7={17,18,19,20},store8={18,19,20,21}
```

After the first three `sortSwap`s, changed `storen`s are as follows:

```
store1 = {min(1,2),min(2,3),min(3,4),min(4,5)}
store2 = {max(1,2),max(2,3),max(3,4),max(4,5)}
store4 = {min(9,10),min(10,11),min(11,12),min(12,13)}
store5 = {max(9,10),max(10,11),max(11,12),max(12,13)}
store7 = {min(17,18),min(18,19),min(19,20),min(20,21)}
store8 = {max(17,18),max(18,19),max(19,20),max(20,21)}
```

Then after the second three `sortSwap`s, changed `storen` are as follows:

```
store0 = {min(0,1,2),min(1,2,3),min(2,3,4),min(3,4,5)}
store1 = {max(0,1,2),max(1,2,3),max(2,3,4),max(3,4,5)}
store3 = {min(8,9,10),min(9,10,11),min(10,11,12),min(11,12,13)}
store4 = {max(8,9,10),max(9,10,11),max(10,11,12),max(11,12,13)}
store6 = {min(16,17,18),min(17,18,19),min(18,19,20),min(19,20,21)}
store7 = {max(16,17,18),max(17,18,19),max(18,19,20),max(19,20,21)}
```

Next, after the third three `sortSwap`s, changed `storen` are as follows:

```
store1 = {max(1,2),max(2,3),max(3,4),max(4,5)}
store2 = {max(0,1,2),max(1,2,3),max(2,3,4),max(3,4,5)}
store4 = {max(9,10),max(10,11),max(11,12),max(12,13)}
store5 = {max(8,9,10),max(9,10,11),max(10,11,12),max(11,12,13)}
store7 = {max(17,18),max(18,19),max(19,20),max(20,21)}
store8 = {max(16,17,18),max(17,18,19),max(18,19,20),max(19,20,21)}
```

...
Now start the sixth three `sortSwap`s, changed `storen` are as follows:

```
store4[0] = median(max(1,2),max(9,10),max(17,18))
store4[1] = median(max(2,3),max(10,11),max(18,19))
store4[2] = median(max(3,4),max(11,12),max(19,20))
store4[3] = median(max(4,5),max(12,13),max(20,21))
...
```

Above is my stiff thread, I cannot continue my inference on calculating the sixth three `sortSwap`s. So, can anyone give me a clearer interpretation of above codes?

Comment: I recommend reading about [Sorting Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network)

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2786959/253056) regarding using sorting networks.