# How does DeepMind's *new sorting algorithm* compare to human optimized algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Looks like [DeepMind's new sorting algorithm](https://www.deepmind.com/blog/alphadev-discovers-faster-sorting-algorithms) is quite similar to those tried in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786899/fastest-sort-of-fixed-length-6-int-array)

If we adapt it to the settings of the SO question, how does it actually compare to what humans proposed?

Comment: I think calling its modification *a new sorting algorithm* hyperbole. It looks similar to what the GNU "superoptimizer" did (does?). It is not *discovering a new algorithm*, but *implementing a worth-while micro-optimisation*.

Comment: Yes, but that was also what we users of SO basically did in the linked question. Which could lead to some interesting comparisons (I'm also wondering why posters did not found that specific micro optimization as the answers were quite thorough).